# google Structured Data Testing Tool error

Tags: javascript, seo, schema, markup, schema.org

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
  "name" : "website.com",
  "description": "About. asdadsad ",
  "image" : "http://website.com/image.png",
  "telephone" : "123456789",
  "email" : "mail@com",
  "address" : {
      "@type" : "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress" : "N1 Big street",
      "addressLocality" : "city",
      "addressCountry" : "Country"
},
  "url" : "http://somesite.com/",
   "sameAs" : ["http://www.facebook.com/",
   "http://twitter.com",
   "http://plus.google.com/"],
   "aggregateRating" : {
       "@type" : "AggregateRating",
       "ratingValue" : "4",
       "bestRating" : "5",
       "worstRating" : "0"
},
</script>
```

This is my created code for web schema, but when I try to test on [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) it returns the error :

> JSON-LD: There was an error parsing your JSON-LD.

How do I fix this? Which error do I have in this code ?

Comment: JSON-LD: There was an error parsing your JSON-LD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is missing a closing bracket `}` at the end.

Your last `}` is closing the `aggregateRating` propriety and you have none to close your object.

Just add a `}` and it works.

PS : your `AggregateRating` object is missing a `ratingCount` or `reviewCount`.

Here is an fixed version of your code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
  "name" : "website.com",
  "description": "About. asdadsad ",
  "image" : "http://website.com/image.png",
  "telephone" : "123456789",
  "email" : "mail@com",
  "address" : {
    "@type" : "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress" : "N1 Big street",
    "addressLocality" : "city",
    "addressCountry" : "Country"
  },
  "url" : "http://somesite.com/",
  "sameAs" : [
    "http://www.facebook.com/",
    "http://twitter.com",
    "http://plus.google.com/"
  ],
  "aggregateRating" : {
    "@type" : "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue" : 4,
    "bestRating" : 5,
    "worstRating" : 0,
    "ratingCount" : 12
  }
}
</script>
```